# Is there a way to edit cell text based upon proximity to other blank cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel report that is the product of another financial program.  I am using this program's output to develop another comprehensive report using index/match and other excel functions.  I am having an issue, although, with the formatting given by the program.  (View image attached)

Basically I need the ***highlighted*** code text to be copied down over the subsequent codes until the blank cells are reached, then repeat for the next highlighted code.  This goes down many rows where the highlighted code at the top of the block needs to replace the following codes but stop once the two blank cells are hit.  Is there any way of achieving this without a macro, possibly using some form of Offset formula?  If a macro must be used, then this will suffice as well.  The finance program will not let me change the format, but I need these unique identifiers for the purpose of a pivot table.  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick if there are always 2 blank lines between the codes to be copied. If not it will take a little more work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCodes()

   Dim lCurRow   As Long
   Dim lLastRow  As Long
   Dim zCopyCode As String
   
   lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count
   lLastRow = Cells(lLastRow, 1).End(xlUp).Row() + 1
   
   zCopyCode = Cells(2, 1).Value
   Debug.Print zCopyCode
   lCurRow = 3
  
   Do
     
     If (Cells(lCurRow, 1) <> "" And _
         Cells(lCurRow, 2) <> "") Then
       Cells(lCurRow, 1) = zCopyCode
       lCurRow = lCurRow + 1
     Else
       If (Cells(lCurRow, 1) = "" And _
           Cells(lCurRow, 2) = "") Then
         lCurRow = lCurRow + 2  'Skip 2 blank rows to next code
         zCopyCode = Cells(lCurRow, 1).Value
         lCurRow = lCurRow + 1  'Move to first row to possibly copy over
       End If
       
     End If
    
   Loop Until lCurRow = lLastRow
   
End Sub  'CopyCodes
```

HTH